# Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing following SQL procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spc_InsertSubjectToContentRelation]
(
    @pCourseGUID XML, 
    @pSubjectId XML,
    @pAssessmentIds XML,
    @pVideoIds XML
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CourseGUID NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @SubjectId NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @AssessmentIds NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @VideoIds NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @CourseGUID = Convert(NVARCHAR,@pCourseGUID);
    SET @SubjectId = Convert(NVARCHAR,@pSubjectId);
    SET @AssessmentIds = Convert(NVARCHAR,@pAssessmentIds);
    SET @VideoIds = Convert(NVARCHAR,@pVideoIds);

    INSERT INTO SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation VALUES (@pCourseGUID, @pAssessmentIds, @pAssessmentIds, @pVideoIds)
END
```

When I'm running this procedure I'm getting the error:

> Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
>   How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why would you declare the parameters as one type if that's not the type that your procedure wants?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because the type of columns in the table is not of xml type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the conversions and then ignore the converted values and continue to use the original parameter values. You might have wanted this:

```
INSERT INTO SubjectToAssessmentAndVideoRelation VALUES (
     @CourseGUID, @AssessmentIds, @AssessmentIds, @VideoIds)
```

(No `p` after the `@`, and thus using the local variables rather than the parameters)

But I continue to be mystified why you declare your procedure to want `xml` parameters if it's going to immediately convert them to `nvarchar`s.